# Date Format Issue in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I am currently using **ASP.NET MVC5(C#) in VS2013**. I am using **Kendo datepicker and datetime picker** for date inputs in views. The issue is while testing locally date validation happen as per local pc so date is right in my pc but not in my colleague pc. Just beacuse his and mine pc date time formate is different. But when I run same live application from server, no issue in anyone's pc. How could I solve this issue of same date format for any pc?

Note: There is no default dateformat in web.config. We are following en-US format.

Comment: Send a date object instead of a string (which will be sent as ISO date format) ?

Comment: @FlorianF. It's passing as date only.

Comment: You need to set the localization of the entire application on `Application_Start`.

Comment: @AndreiV, can u explain how?

Comment: Kendo reads the current application localization for both the application and the UI. This, of course, depends on both the application settings and browser settings. You can, however, set the localization by code. This means the all the users and all pages will have the same localization so be sure that it's something you really really need/want. If so, set `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` to the desired culture (e.g. "en-US"). Set them in `Global.asax` on `Application_Start` or `Session_Start`. Try other "start" methods as well.